# Which book is about JDK1.5+ Thread?

Tags: java

I wanna learn about Java Thread.and I wanna learn new feature of JDK 1.5+.
So which book is about  new feature of JDK1.5+ Thread?
Thanks.

Comment: I think every book that cover JDK1.5+ did cover such topic.  What exactly are u looking for that is not available in those books?

Comment: what is it with the book questions. go to your library, get a book, live it, breathe it, move on

Comment: AFAIK, there are no new features in the `Thread` class in Java 1.5.  Perhaps you are talking about the concurrency classes?

Answer (score 2):

For threads, and everything else about *concurrency*: [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.jcip.net/) (but it's not a book about Java in general - it requires a working knowledge of Java).